# How to convert an insert SQL query to a PostGIS layer?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql-server

I have hundreds of rows from a SQL Server query which I would like to convert to a PostGIS layer in PostgreSQL

Example of the query:

```
INSERT INTO `qv` (`id`,`qv`,`st_astext(t.Shape)`,`center_shape`,`UNIT_ID`) 
VALUES (13,'2176','POLYGON((19.55677774479716 41.17491235172372,19.55818158561175 41.17550108840453,19.558470650200377 41.17565319883613,19.559655895503226 41.1762216827845,19.55956255846536 41.17634000658609,19.560356167902853 41.17675102913671,19.56038117625036 41.176788220599974,19.558407823562277 41.17881422949313,19.557394583493306 41.17833867788772,19.557008000918586 41.17823290052797,19.553772460530695 41.17668938150979,19.55323508053459 41.176432464986306,19.552840846527886 41.176248868390644,19.551423913382962 41.17555977636266,19.550877047337906 41.175305798823615,19.548128808197987 41.17402938384902,19.548209153629614 41.17395401256766,19.5482443620877 41.173919777176025,19.548708959950602 41.173383917933506,19.548847433961953 41.1732241569693,19.549524140526728 41.17244181423837,19.549786935918405 41.172137968392576,19.55008615025565 41.171792062154,19.554275198641562 41.17397932488598,19.554336819288835 41.173901846493095,19.55677774479716 41.17491235172372))','POINT(19.554302318273688 41.175368836800104)',4);
```

How do I get this into a PostGIS layer?

Comment: We have a policy of "One question per Question", so I removed the references to "or shapefile" (which requires a very different solution).

Answer (score 3):

If you strip out the backticks, it's a legal insert statement, so you just need to create a destination table and load it up.

```
CREATE TABLE qv (
  id integer primary key,
  qv text,
  shape geometry,
  center_shape geometry,
  unit_id integer 
);
```

If you have a linux commandline, you can condition the sql file and load it in one step:

```
cat sqlserver.sql | tr -d '`' | | sed 's/st_astext(t.Shape)/shape/' | psql mydatabase
```

Really if you can get your insert into a clean postgresql form using a text editor you'll be in fine shape

- Replace all ` with nothing
- Replace all "st_astext(t.Shape)" with "shape"

So you end up with something like:

```
INSERT INTO qv (id,qv,shape,center_shape,UNIT_ID) 
VALUES (13,'2176','POLYGON((..removed for readability..))','POINT(19.554302318273688 41.175368836800104)',4);
```

Comment: that will yield an error that you cannot insert text into geometry column.

Comment: I got this error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `qv` (`id`,`qv`,`st_astext(t.Shape)`,`center_sha...
                    ^


Query returned successfully in 3 secs.

Comment: @ShefqetLULJA Sure, because there is no source for t.Shape. That is why in my answer I explained a bit more the backgrounds instead of providing a ready-to-use answer.

Comment: The problem is the `st_astext(t.Shape)` part in the insert, but also your attempt to load seems to have not stripped out all the backticks, so there's multiple issues to clean out. Somewhat uglier than I hoped, but if you truly only have "a few hundred rows" you could clean up your SQL just using a text editor and search/replace functions.

Comment: @RoVo, postgis will happily read correctly formatted text into geometry columns, the constructor functions aren't required. Try "SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::geometry for example. That's all that happens implicitly in an INSERT statement.

Comment: @PaulRamsey . Great ! I didn't know that :-)

Comment: Yes, i loaded those all now, but i did it on sql spatial, then i opened through Qgis which i saved the layer as shape file. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

The `POLYGON( ... )` and `POINT( ... )` parts of the insert command are [WKT Geometries (Well Known Text)](http://giswiki.org/wiki/Well_Known_Text).
You can use the PostGIS command [`ST_GeomFromText(text WKT, integer srid);`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) to convert them to Geometry type.

There are many ways to achieve the expected result:

You can create a PostgreSQL table with the necessary columns and `INSERT` your query into that table. Convert the text field holding the wkt to geometry using `UPDATE`, `INSERT INTO`, or `CREATE TABLE ... AS` OR use any Text Editor to extract the WKT manually and insert them directly.

I would probably create a temporary table `qv_temp` and insert your queries almost as they are (you need to remove the backticks). Then create the target PostGIS table using [`CREATE TABLE qv AS ....`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtableas.html) using `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT()` here.

or

use your favorite text editor and replace the inserts `'POLYGON(...)'` part with `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON(...)')`.

Don't forget to have a primary key and to create indexes on the geometry column of the resulting table.